# Nestjs get user from jwt token returns 401 Unauthorized error

Tags: node.js, session, oauth, jwt, nestjs

i'm making google-auth site, and i made custom user-decorator and it can't return user.

```
@UseGuards(AuthGuard('jwt'))
  @Get('profile')
  getProfile(@UserDecorator() user: User) {
    return user;
  }
```

this is my controller's code

```
import { createParamDecorator, ExecutionContext } from '@nestjs/common';

export const UserDecorator = createParamDecorator(
  (data: unknown, ctx: ExecutionContext) => {
    const request = ctx.switchToHttp().getRequest();
    console.log(request)
    return request.user;
  },
);
```

this is my custom user decorator.

my controller's function supposed to return user's info using by JWT (parsing)
but this function return's 401 error , so when i delete

```
@UseGuards(AuthGuard('jwt'))
```

and my custom decorator 's console.log(request) returns....->>

[image]

this kind of something strange object.
i checked with f12 button, and jwt token was exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If when you remove:

```
@UseGuards(AuthGuard('jwt'))
```

you don't receive the `401` error again, it means that you haven't done the login before you call the API.

Comment: thanks. then adding authguard and getting 401error means ..?